# Making a bar graph to compare boolean data counts in R

Tags: r

I have a data set of 13 columns and 91 rows. Each column contains a boolean value TRUE or FALSE. These are responses to a survey where participants were asked which app they drove for - uber, lyft, postmates, etc. Is it possible to create a bar graph which compares the count of TRUE values in each of these columns to the others? I'd like the y axis to be the count (0-91), and the x axis to include the labels "uber, lyft, postmates..." and so on. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: `dat <- data.frame(mtcars > 0); barplot(sapply(dat, function(x) table(factor(x, c(FALSE, TRUE)))))`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll read over the link you posted right now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier and provide accurate help for your case if you provide reproducible example as @Limely said.

I guess your data looks like

```
df <- data.frame(
  uber = c(T,T,T,F,T),
  lyft = c(F,F,T,F,F),
  postmates = c(T,T,F,F,F),
  etc = c(T,F,F,F,F)
)
   uber  lyft postmates   etc
1  TRUE FALSE      TRUE  TRUE
2  TRUE FALSE      TRUE FALSE
3  TRUE  TRUE     FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE     FALSE FALSE
5  TRUE FALSE     FALSE FALSE
```

Then simply

```
barplot(colSums(df))
```

will give

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. That's exactly what I was looking for. And in the future, I'll try to provide better examples.